# Unable to install grpc on Ubuntu 16.0

Tags: c++, linux, grpc, ubuntu-16.04, vcpkg

I'm installing grpc via vcpkg on Ubuntu 16.04 inside docker.

```
./vcpkg install vcpkg:x64-linux
```

on the stdout:

```
-- Building x64-linux-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:129 (message):
    Command failed: /home/techstar/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.24.0-linux/cmake-3.24.0-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v -j13
    Working Directory: /home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/x64-linux-dbg
    See logs for more information:
      /home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/install-x64-linux-dbg-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-linux/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:74 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  installed/x64-linux/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:16 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
  ports/grpc/portfile.cmake:69 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


error: building grpc:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILED
error: Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+grpc
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[grpc]+Build+error
Include '[grpc] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-09-20-522aa94e9d261c7d7b2f079bf2591ca62df5c714
    vcpkg-scripts version: fe57571 2022-10-05 (13 hours ago)
```

Inside the log:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc.o 
/usr/bin/c++ -DCARES_STATICLIB -I/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/include -I/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean -I/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -I/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/third_party/xxhash -isystem /home/techstar/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -fPIC  -g -fPIC -pthread -std=c++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc.o -c /home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc
/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc:48:20:   in constexpr expansion of ‘((grpc_core::{anonymous}::UrlTable*)(& grpc_core::{anonymous}::g_url_table))->grpc_core::{anonymous}::UrlTable::UrlTable()’
/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc:38:41:   in constexpr expansion of ‘((grpc_core::{anonymous}::UrlTable*)this)->grpc_core::{anonymous}::UrlTable::<anonymous>.grpc_core::BitSet<kTotalBits, kUnitBits>::set<256ul, 64ul>(i)’
/home/techstar/vcpkg/buildtrees/grpc/src/v1.49.0-b3763f9139.clean/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.cc:48:20: internal compiler error: in fold_binary_loc, at fold-const.c:9921
 constexpr UrlTable g_url_table;
                    ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

Am I missing some dependenciy or is this a bug? Dose anyone have any Idea?

Comment: "internal compiler error" is a pretty big clue that the compiler couldn't handle some of the code and fell over. That should never happen, so probably a compiler bug - you could try a newer (or different) compiler and/or report a compiler bug.

Comment: We have the same issue, but with GRPC 1.50.0
I haven't been able to make head nor tails of it yet.
We're thinking ubuntu 16 is just too old.